# Why is RIPEMD160 not avaible in VeraCrypt anymore?

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

Any weekness found? Because I updated my VC to the new version 1.21 and it is not. Any details about it?

Comment: This is a question for the VeraCrypt team/product, not an infosec question.   A shot in the dark that the change might be due to a security issue does not a good question make.

Comment: Oh sorry for dont know the telephone number of the VeraCrypt team and ask to they directly

Comment: They have a website.  The same one you get the software from.  It has forums.

Answer (score 3):

Literally the first google result -
https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/30c2375f/

> RIPEMD-160 was indeed deprecated for creating non-system volumes starting from version 1.0f released on December 30th, 2014 but it is still possible to mount volumes using RIPEMD-160
>
> RIPEMD-160 is an old algorithm that has been deprecated by all major security solutions in favor of more modern algorithms. And although there is no publicly known attack against it, its aging design coupled with new advances in attacks techniques make it risky to continue relying on it.
>
> That being said, RIPEMD-160 is still available for system encryption since it is the only alternative available to SHA-256, and you can still
>   For non-system encryption, Whirlpool is a strong alternative to the SHA-2 family for those seeking a non US designed algorithm.
>
> Hopefully in the near future, new secure hash algorithms like SHA-3, Skein or BLAKE will be included to offer more alternatives.

Mounir Idrassi is the author of VeraCrypt. Here is the commit where it was deprecated for Linux/MacOSX.

https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/commit/2c96d17748eaff6fd77453b58476d965e54d59d7